# delete queue in ActiveMq cluster?

Tags: activemq-classic

I configure a activemq cluster using JDBC Master Slave,My requirement is when i using a the queue i should delete it ,using jmx can delete a queue if you konw the broker jmxserviceurl ,but in cluster,i can't konw which broker the queue create on,so is there any other way to down this?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you "garbace collect" them instead and you won't have to worry to much about unused queues cluttering down the cluster?

http://activemq.apache.org/delete-inactive-destinations.html